# Script appending "=s1400" to image src path and now image will not load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I understand HTML/CSS pretty well, but not JavaScript. There is a script appending "=s1400" after image path. Why? Image will not load because of this. URL is https://zenith-express.com/airfreight.html (source files can be seen with Chrome DevTools).

Source HTML:

```
<img  id="vbid-cfb2edc5-mm7avm4t" class="blocks-inner-pic preview-element  magic-circle-holder  load-high-res shrinkable-img" data-menu-name="HEADER_IMAGE"  src="https://zenith-express.com/imgs/af_service_area.png" data-orig-width="688" data-orig-height="420" />
```

Displayed HTML:

```
<img id="vbid-cfb2edc5-mm7avm4t" class="blocks-inner-pic preview-element  magic-circle-holder  shrinkable-img" data-menu-name="HEADER_IMAGE" src="https://zenith-express.com/imgs/af_service_area.png=s1400" data-orig-width="688" data-orig-height="420" data-width-before-shrink="700" style="background-image: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

I needed to add "data-width-before-shrink="700" to image tag like this:

```
<img id="vbid-cfb2edc5-mm7avm4t" class="blocks-inner-pic preview-element  magic-circle-holder  shrinkable-img" data-menu-name="HEADER_IMAGE" src="./imgs/af_service_area.png" data-orig-width="688" data-orig-height="420" data-width-before-shrink="700" style="background-image: none;">
```